# How to make sure directory only has specific subdirectories?

Tags: directory, rm, mkdir

I have a directory that has some subdirectories with files in them. I have another directory that  has very similar subdirectories but there may be a few that are added or removed. How can I add and remove subdirectories so the two directories have the same structure?

Is there a simple way to do this using a command or tool? Or do I have to do something more complicated like search through every subdirectory and check if it has a matching one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this answer I used the following tools:

- Bash
- `comm`
- `find`
- `xargs`

I recommend you to use the GNU version of the last 3 utilities as they can deal with NUL-delimited records.

First, let's declare some variables. It's necessary to use absolute pathnames in all these variables as we'll be changing directories many times:

```bsh
# The directories that will be compared
original_dir='/path/to/original/directory'
copy_dir='/path/to/copy/directory'

# Text files where we will save the structure of both directories
original_structure="${HOME}/original_structure.txt"
copy_structure="${HOME}/copy_structure.txt"

# Text files where we will separate each subdirectory
# depending on the action we will perform on them
dirs_to_add="${HOME}/dirs_to_add.txt"
dirs_to_remove="${HOME}/dirs_to_remove.txt"
```

Save the current structure of both directories:

```bsh
cd -- "${original_dir}"
find . \! -name '.' -type 'd' -print0 | sort -z > "${original_structure}"

cd -- "${copy_dir}"
find . \! -name '.' -type 'd' -print0 | sort -z > "${copy_structure}"
```

Save the differences between both structures:

```bsh
comm -23 -z -- "${original_structure}" "${copy_structure}" > "${dirs_to_add}"
comm -13 -z -- "${original_structure}" "${copy_structure}" > "${dirs_to_remove}"
```

Create the missing directories:

```bsh
cd -- "${copy_dir}"
xargs -0 mkdir -p -- < "${dirs_to_add}"
```

Remove the unwanted directories:

```bsh
cd -- "${copy_dir}"
xargs -0 rm -rf -- < "${dirs_to_remove}"
```

Remove the text files we created to save the temporal information:

```bsh
rm -- "${original_structure}" "${copy_structure}"
rm -- "${dirs_to_add}" "${dirs_to_remove}"
```

---

## Notes

- This method only copies the structure. It doesn't preserve owners, permissions or attributes. I read that some other tools, like `rsync`, could preserve them, but I have no experience using them.
- If you want to put the code above into a script, make sure to implement error handling. For instance, failing to `cd` into a directory and operating in the incorrect one may lead to catastrophic consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this shell function might do:

```
comparedirs() (
    cd -- "${1?}";
    for d in */; do
        ! [ -d ../"${2?}"/"$d" ] && printf "%s\n" "$d is in '$1' but not in '$2'"
    done
)
```

A test:

```
$ mkdir -p left/{a,b,c}
$ mkdir -p right/{a,c,d}
$ comparedirs left right
b/ is in 'left' but not in 'right'
$ comparedirs right left
d/ is in 'right' but not in 'left'
```

Note, that only looks at subdirectories, not files; and assumes the directories indeed are siblings, i.e. that you can reach one from the other with `../name`. <sub>(Generalizing to other situation is left as an exercise for the next answer.)</sub>